# How to print traditional Chinese characters on Epson TM-T20 (USB)

Tags: c#, encoding, cjk

**Background:** I am developing a POS software in C# which requires to print traditional Chinese characters on the receipt.

**Hardware**: EPSON TM-T20 communicates via USB connection

**Code:**

```
            string text = "鄆";

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            // Traditional Chinese (big5)
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(950);

            // convert the text into a byte array
            byte[] source = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            // convert that byte array to the new codepage. 
            byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, encoding, source);

            // take multi-byte characters and encode them as separate ascii characters 
            string result = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(converted);

            // Print
            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|N" + result + "\n");
```

This is the code provided by jkealey available at http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/01/15/Simplified-Chinese-on-Epson-TM-T88IV-Receipt-Printer.aspx

**Problem:** Before I use the code provided by jkealey, the printer prints out "?" instead of the Chinese characters, but now it prints out "ÜP".

On the Epson TM-T20 utility Ver.1.00, I have the following font settings for Code-page and International character set. ( I am not able to post an image as I am a new user)

Code-Page: PC850 (Multilingual)
international character set: China

I am not sure where I have gone wrong in this.

Comment: I don't know anything about C#, but `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` seems suspicious. If you already have a byte array, you shouldn't need to convert "multi-byte characters as separate ascii characters". I'm pretty sure your encoding is screwing up somewhere around there.

Comment: That's because PrintNormal bypasses the printer driver, Notepad doesn't.  The printer driver takes care of the complexity of mapping a font with Chinese glyphs to pixels.  Finding a POS printer that supports Chinese fonts natively should be challenging.  Use, say, the PrintDocument class to print through the driver.

Comment: PrintDocument class will be a whole new implementation for the Printing function for my program. Is it possible to turn the string which contain chinese into bitmap and send the bitmap to the printer by using the PrintNormal?